# How do I scale a 0.5-4.5v signal to a 0-3.3v signal?

Tags: analog

I am trying to scale down the analog value of a pressure sensor to an analog value that my mcp3008 analog to digital converter can read. The pressure sensor outputs a voltage between 0.5v and 4.5v while the mcp3008 takes in analog signals between 0v and 3.3v. I have read about voltage dividers, but it seems to me that in this case that would be really imprecise. If I just divide the max voltage of 4.5 down to 3.3 aren't I losing a lot of resolution due to the range of the pressure sensor output starting at 0.5v?

Comment: Why not simply increase the supply voltage? It sounds like you have a 5V rail, so could you use that for Vref instead of 3.3? Or, if it's a dirty 5V, regulate it down to Vref=4.5V?

Comment: Do you have access to a reference voltage and an opamp?

Comment: From what I've read I can't use 5v or 4.5v for the Vref as the mcp3008 is connected to a raspberry pi, and the gpio pins can't handle the output from the mcp3008 at that voltage.

Comment: Do you need 4.5v out to produce 3.3v precisely? If not, you could get close with a 12k & 4.7k combo, yielding a range around .37 to 3.23v. The resulting voltage may be imprecise, but the scaling would be consistent throughout the range - about 72% of the sensor's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple potential divider rescaler would only be "throwing away" (0.5 / 4.5) = 11% of the resolution.  To me it seems likely that the simplicity of the potential divider (vs the minimum of one op-amp + passives that would be needed for an active analog subtractor) is worth it, especially when you consider that the additional circuitry would introduce some amount of noise and scale/offset error.

As a bonus if you preserve the ability to read below the sensor's minimum specified output value, then you may be able to detect a failed or unconnected sensor.

Comment: Agreed. For most applications, a diff amp analog subtractor just isn't worth the effort when a resistor divider will get what you need.

Comment: Alright then slightly dumber question, the pressure sensor I have takes 5v of power, while outputting a voltage between 0.5v and 4.5v. Am I correct that I am still only dividing down from 4.5v to 3.3v since even though the pressure sensor takes 5v of power, the signal it outputs will only ever be between 0.5v and 4.5v.

Comment: @qwhii Yes, that should be safe.  Even if the sensor (or the wiring to it) were faulty in such a way as to connect the sensor output to 5V, the MCP3008 input would get 3.67V which is within its absolute maximum voltage rating (Vdd+0.6V per the datasheet).

Comment: Although you might want to choose the scaling to encompass a slightly larger range than the expected sensor output - e.g. 4.6V - so that even if component tolerances stack up to a few percent, you still won't "rail" the ADC, and you'll be able to calibrate the full scale range in software.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no simple purely passive way to accurately scale that range to 3.3V-0. You can do it with more circuitry, but I imagine that that would be an unnecessary hassle.

As you mentioned, you can use a voltage divider. I would use high value resistors for it (at least 10k, probably more like 50k) to prevent them from loading the measurement.

You would actually only be losing a small amount, 0.35V, of your range, and this doesnt matter much. Your ADC has 10 bit precision, so with a divider, it's measuring the original range with an effective resolution of 4.39mV. If you did scale it "properly" it would have a resolution of 3.9mV. This is less than half a mV, which could easily be below the noise floor anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is scale and apply offset.

Something like this (only you need a rail-rail CMOS op-amp to do it). 
Here I show setting to scale a 4 V signal to 3 V and apply an offset, easily altered to suit your needs if you need headroom to detect faults.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpa4wg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>